# How to make Eloquent push a child Collection inside its parent Collection?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I didn't know how to ask this question but i'll do my best.

- My `Subcategories`  table has a one-to-one relation with the `Categories` table
- My `Subcategories` table has a `many-to-many` relation with the
  `Subtags` table.
- My table `Subtags` has a relation `one-to-many` with the `Tags`
  table.

I have a `Categories` Table

```
+------+--------+
+  id  +  name  +
+------+--------+
```

I have a `Subcategories` Table

```
+------+----------------+--------+
+  id  +  categories_id +  name  +
+------+----------------+--------+

Class Subcategory {
    public function category()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('Category', 'id', 'categories_id');
    }

    public function subtags()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Subtag', 'subcategories_has_subtags', 'subcategories_id', 'subtags_id');
    }
}
```

I have a `Tags` Table

```
+------+--------+
+  id  +  name  +
+------+--------+

Class Tag {
    public function subtag()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('Subtag', 'tags_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I have a `Subtags` Table

```
+------+----------+--------+
+  id  +  tags_id +  name  +
+------+----------+--------+

Class Subtag {
    public function subcategories()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Subcategory', 'subcategories_has_subtags', 'subtags_id', 'subcategories_id');
    }

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Tag', 'id', 'tags_id');
    }
}
```

I have this query:

```
Post::find($id)->with('categories.subcategories.subtags');
```

What Eloquent return with this query:

```
Post Collection Test 
     => Category Collection 
          => Subcategory Collection
              => Subtag Collection 1
                  => Tag Collection (tags_id) 1
              => Subtag Collection 2
                  => Tag Collection (tags_id) 1
              => Subtag Collection 3
                  => Tag Collection (tags_id) 1
              => Subtag Collection 4
                  => Tag Collection (tags_id) 2
```

What I want:

```
Post Collection Test 
     => Category Collection 
          => Subcategory Collection
              => Tag Collection (tags_id) 1
                  => Subtag Collection 1
                  => Subtag Collection 2
                  => Subtag Collection 3
              => Tag Collection (tags_id) 2
                  => Subtag Collection 4
```

Is it possible using Eloquent? Or do I have to this manually?

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1 You can do `with('categories.subcategories.subtags')` instead of those nested closures. 2 It's unclear of what you asking, so rephrase your question and add an example.

Comment: Yes sorry, my vocabulary is limited, I don't have the exact words. I already add an example of what I want Eloquent to return.

Comment: Don't worry about vocab, I mean only that it is unclear. Show the tables involved and what result you need. BTW `Post::find($id)->with(..)->get()` is a bit wrong - `find` already fetched the result, then you run another query with `get`.

Comment: Yes sorry I copy/paste many line an did modifications..

You can check my udpate if it helps more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first! Your relation is wrong here:

```
// Subtag model
public function tag()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Tag', 'id', 'tags_id');
}
```

it should be:

```
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Tag', 'tags_id', 'id');
}
```

Now, since `subcategories - tags` and `subcategories - subtags` are separate relations, you can't do what you asked for, with Eloquent features. You can do it manually on the collections, however I would reconsider your whole schema. Are you sure you want all those **Sub** models and tables?

Mind that you can use `SubCategory` model using the same table as for `Category` model but with a global scope, just so you know.

Comment: Yes You're totally right.. my mistake, I've never seen this mistake cause I never use this method.

And like you said I should reconsider my schema.